# Long paragraph breaks list layout

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list with `list-style-type:none` to which I manually added bullets using `:before`.

The problem here is that if a paragraph inside one of the `<li>`s gets long enough to wrap around, the width of the paragraph itself will be too long to fit behind the bullet and so it gets pushed to a new line:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;  
}
li {
    padding:0 0 0 .5em;
}
li:before {
    content:"- "; 
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
li > p {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    /*max-width:calc(100% - 2em);*/
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><p>Looks normal</p></li>
    <li><p>Looks normal with a<br>line break too.</p></li>
    <li><p>If a line is long enough, it wraps (as it should) and the layout is somehow destroyed. Just adding some more text to make sure the text wraps.</p></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1xaamone/

As you can see in my example, I already have a workaround, but I wonder if there's a solution that works without `calc()` to improve browser compatibility even further.

Comment: just change your css for `p` tag to `display:inline;`

Comment: Already tried, doesn't work: If I do that, the second line of a paragraph starts too far left.

Comment: In that case you can try `max-width:some_value px;` Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/1xaamone/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `white-space: nowrap` on the parent `li` element and then reset that by setting `white-space: normal` on the child `p` element:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/3xdu65pv/)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  padding: 0 .5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
li::before {
  content: "- ";
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
li > p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><p>Looks normal</p></li>
    <li><p>Looks normal with a<br>line break too.</p></li>
    <li><p>If a line is long enough, it wraps (as it should) and the layout is somehow destroyed. Just adding some more text to make sure the text wraps.</p></li>
</ul>
```

---

Alternatively, you could also absolutely position the pseudo element *relative* to the parent `li` element and then displace it with padding.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hmaLe6ht/)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  padding: 0 .5em;
  position: relative;
}
li::before {
  content: "- ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
li > p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><p>Looks normal</p></li>
    <li><p>Looks normal with a<br>line break too.</p></li>
    <li><p>If a line is long enough, it wraps (as it should) and the layout is somehow destroyed. Just adding some more text to make sure the text wraps.</p></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the `<p>` tags also works.
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/colost8rams/v2m2ose4/)

```
<ul>
<li>Looks normal</li>
<li>Looks normal with a<br>line break too.</li>
<li>If a line is long enough, it wraps (as it should) and the layout is somehow destroyed. Just adding some more text to make sure the text wraps.</li>
```

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;  
}
li {
    padding:0 0 0 .5em;
}
li:before {
    content:"- "; 
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
li > p {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;

    /*max-width:calc(100% - 2em);*/
}
```

Comment: Although I neglected to ask if you were using you using the `<p>` tags for another purpose.

Comment: But then the paragraph lines aren't inline/indented http://i.stack.imgur.com/4rhCK.png

Comment: Ah, I knew it was too simple.  Thanks for the calcification @josh.